# $_POST is empty when submitting a form

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- SCRIPTS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controller.js"></script>
        <!-- STYLES -->
        <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $errUrl = $videoId = "";
    $start = $end = 0;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        print_r($_POST);
        if (isset($_POST["yt_url"])) {
            echo "hello2";
            $videoId = youtube_parser($_POST['yt_url']);
        }
        if (!$videoId) {
            $errUrl = "URL is not valid!";
            $videoId = "";
        } else {
            $errUrl = "";
        }
        //$start = $_POST['startH'] * 3600 + $_POST['startM'] * 60 + $_POST['startS'] * 1;
        //$end = $_POST['endH'] * 3600 + $_POST['endM'] * 60 + $_POST['endS'] * 1;
    }

    function youtube_parser($url) {
        $regExp = '/^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$/';
        $match = preg_match($regExp, $url, $matches);
        return ($match && strlen($matches[5]) === 11)? $matches[5] : false;
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
    ?>
        <div class="left">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $errUrl; ?></span><br>
                URL: <input type="text" name="yt_url">
                <br><br>
                Start Time:<br>
                <span class="label">Hour: </span><input value="0" type="number" name="start_h"><br>
                <span class="label">Minute: </span><input value="0" type="number" name="start_m"><br>
                <span class="label">Second: </span><input value="0" type="number" name="start_s">
                <br><br>
                End Time:<br>
                <span class="label">Hour: </span><input value="0" type="number" name="end_h"><br>
                <span class="label">Minute: </span><input value="0" type="number" name="end_m"><br>
                <span class="label">Second: </span><input value="0" type="number" name="end_s">
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="player"><?php
            if (isset($videoId) && !empty($videoId)) {
                echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$videoId?start=$start&end=$end" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
            }
            ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above is what I have so far. I am attempting to learn php, and I have been working through the tutorials on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/) I got to the part about working with forms, and none of the information is being passed in the $_POST array, I have set names for all of my DOM controls. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! I have a feeling it my have something to do with my PHP setup as even the provided example doesn't work.

Additional Information:
Web server running through Intellij PHPStorm.
php version is 7.0.9

[image: Screenshot of product]

Comment: show your HTML form

Comment: try to use `isset($_POST['submit'])` than `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski there is a link at the bottom of post for the output.

Comment: @CarlJan instead of? or first?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski then I must retort "ARE YOU KIDDING ME?" The html is in the post.

Comment: @CoryBariteau Argh. My bad. Did not notice the scrollbar. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks valid and when I tried it it shows expected output from `$_POST` array:
[image]

So it looks like you got problems with environment you are testing it on.

BTW `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`
is wrong. Aside from spaghetti code, you should not use `htmlspecialchars()` here but `urlencode()`
(yet I'd use nothing `_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` cannot be spoofed by client).

Also as @CarlJan suggested you may want to use `isset($_POST['submit'])` to check if your form was submitted as this will condition will only be true if your `submit` button is sent via `POST`. For now you are checking if this is POST request (in general) but it is not the same as it can be post from other form, or triggered by hand.

Comment: Okay, so any ideas as to why the $_POST array would be empty on my end?

Comment: Seems to have something to do with running it in PHPStorm by JetBrains

Comment: It's not problem of your code. Perhaps runtime environement? Upload your script to any hosting and try. And for further development I recommend using i.e. Vagrant based VM instead of half-baked built-in IDE solutions or things like XMMP or so.

Comment: Yes, those were my findings aswell, I was using the built-in server which has a bug that was preventing $_POST from being populated. I just copied the files over to my host and viola, works like a charm, Thanks for you assistance. +1

Comment: Welcome. Bugs in dev tools are common but this for some reason is last thing that comes to mind :)